# Jax-rs Cache control header in response does not work

Tags: java, rest, caching, jax-rs, httpresponse

I am trying to cache the response of rest service but at every subsequent request request is sent to server. I am not sure what is I am missing in the code. I am using JAX-RS for setting the cache headers. Initially I thought it is due to query parameter in the request, so i removed that but caching didn't work even after that.

This is what I have written:

```
@GET
@Path("/primeNumber")
public Response prime() {
    String number = "3";
    boolean isPrime = true;
    int numberInt = Integer.valueOf(number);
    for (int i = 2; i <= numberInt/2 ; i++) {
        if (numberInt % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
    cacheControl.setMaxAge(60000);

    long current = new Date().getTime();
    Date expires = new Date(current + (100 * 1_000));

    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(isPrime).expires(expires).cacheControl(cacheControl).build();
}
```

and my response header look like:

[image: Response Headers]

I have tried with Chrome, Firefox and Advanced REST client(Chrome extension ) for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem.Nothing wrong with the way I have implemented this but I was testing it by browser refresh and as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40151783/cache-control-not-working-when-hit-refresh-in-the-browser), refreshing the window will send a request to server. When I tested the same code via link navigation, it worked fine.